# How to resize an image cropping it equally on each side with CSS

Tags: html, image, css

I have an `img` banner that is automatically created by the framework I'm using.

The code generated is this:

```
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 1282px;">
    <img id="5" runat="server" alt="" src="http://preciosa.myciashop.com.br/Assets/Banner/3/banner1.jpg " style="border:0;" width="1680px" height="434px">
</div>
```

What I want is: When the browser width is smaller than `1680px` the image starts to be cropped equally on each side, so that after some resizing only the girls face is visible (the center of the image).

The image: http://preciosa.myciashop.com.br/Assets/Banner/3/banner1.jpg

I know it's easy to do if I set the image as div's background image, but I can't. I have to do that only using CSS and the HTML structure I've described.

Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: Can't use CSS at all, or just can't set it as a background? I guess I'm asking what _is_ in the realm of possible changes that can be made? HTML/CSS additions?

Comment: If the framework literally creates that, it's time to find another framework. The generated HTML has errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `position:absolute` for the image inside a container with `position: relative` when the viewport is `1679px` wide or less (note: this approach requires to know in advance the height of the parent element, as in your example)

> [Codepen demo (position: absolute)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzVXme)

Markup

```
<div style="width: ...px;">
    <img src="http://.../banner1.jpg" width="1680px" height="434px" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media all and (max-width: 1679px) {
    div { position: relative; 
          height: 434px;
          width: 100% !important; /* to override any inline style */
          overflow: hidden; }

    img { position: absolute; 
          top: 0; left: 50%;
          -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%); }
}
```

---

A modern and elegant approach might use instead the `Flexbox` module, so the `height` of the element is not even necessary on the CSS (and this is better for code reusability)

> [Codepen Demo (display: flex)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxbGej)

```
@media all and (max-width: 1679px) {
    div { 
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100% !important; /* to override any inline style */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which framework you're using, is it possible to remove with width property from HTML? As a best practice, I try to only modify styles with an external CSS file (or internal  tags, but never within HTML tags themselves). I would remove all the style="" sections from the HTML and only modify styles with CSS.

If that's possible, here's my solution:

```css
owl-item {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.owl-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-item">
    <img id="5" runat="server" alt="" src="http://preciosa.myciashop.com.br/Assets/Banner/3/banner1.jpg">
</div>
```

Codepen here -
http://codepen.io/kristywessel/pen/JXGrpo

Comment: I can't remove those... :/

Comment: Can you override them with the important flag? The CSS would look like this:

owl-item {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.owl-item img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Set your image crop dimensions and use this line in your CSS:

```
img {
object-fit: cover;
```

}

you can visit https://medium.com/@chrisnager/center-and-crop-images-with-a-single-line-of-css-ad140d5b4a87#.x7qi8kb24